# Убрать эффект сжатия у ScrollViewer

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, winrt

Пишу под **Windows Phone 8.1** (Universal app) и хочу избавиться от эффекта сжатия при использовании **ScrollViewera**. Например, находясь у края контента, потянуть в противоположную сторону, то весь контент "сожмется" обозначая недоступную область (см. пример).

[image: Находясь в начале списка тянем вниз]

#### Для чего это нужно?

Хочу создать страницу с механикой стартового экрана Windows Phone

[image: введите описание изображения здесь]

#### Что я сделал?

Создал ScrollViewer, добавил ограничивающие элементы в начало и конец содержимого, запретил скроллинг выходящий за границы необходимой области в обработчике события `scrollViewer_ViewChanging(object sender, ScrollViewerViewChangingEventArgs e)`.

**.xaml**

```
<Grid Name="root">
    <ScrollViewer x:Name="scrollViewer" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"  
                                    HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled"   
                                    HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" 
                                    HorizontalSnapPointsType="MandatorySingle"  
                                    ViewChanging="scrollViewer_ViewChanging">
         <StackPanel Name="panel" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
              <Border x:Name="leftSide" Background="Red" Width="{Binding ElementName=root, Path=ActualWidth}"  />
              <Border x:Name="menuBorder" Background="White" Width="{Binding ElementName=root, Path=ActualWidth}"  />
              <Border x:Name="contentBorder" Background="Bisque" Width="{Binding ElementName=root, Path=ActualWidth}"  />
              <Border x:Name="rightSide" Background="Red" Width="{Binding ElementName=root, Path=ActualWidth}"  />
         </StackPanel>
   </ScrollViewer >
</Grid>
```

**.cs**

```
private void МainЗage_Loaded( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    scrollViewer.ChangeView(leftSide.Width,0,1);
}
private void scrollViewer_ViewChanging(object sender, ScrollViewerViewChangingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.NextView.HorizontalOffset <= leftSide.Width)
    {
        scrollViewer.CancelDirectManipulations();
        //scrollViewer.ChangeView(leftSide.Width,0,1,true); 
    } 
    else if (e.NextView.HorizontalOffset >= leftSide.Width + menuBorder.Width + contentBorder.Width)
    {
        scrollViewer.CancelDirectManipulations();
        //scrollViewer.ChangeView(eftSide.Width + menuBorder.Width + contentBorder.Width,0,1,true); 
    }
}
```

Такой код работает, но проскакивают артефакты в виде скачков содержимого, пробовал и закомментированный код, такой же эффект.
Расскажите как исправить мой вариант или подскажите другой подход.

Answer (score 1):

Отнаследуйтесь от контрола, в котором происходит "отпрыгивание" и переопределите метод `UIElement.OnManipulationBoundaryFeedback`:

```
protected override void OnManipulationBoundaryFeedback(ManipulationBoundaryFeedbackEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

См. [UIElement.OnManipulationBoundaryFeedback](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.onmanipulationboundaryfeedback.aspx).

P.S. Не воюйте с системой. Пользователи ожидают отпрыгивание, они привыкли к нему и понимают его. Представьте, что при потягивании списка вниз он будет скроллиться вверх — вот вы делаете примерно то же самое.

Comment: В Windows Phone 8.1 используется другое API - [Windows Runtime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211377.aspx) и у класса 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Control' таких методов нет.  
Я согласен, воевать не стоит, но задуманное поведение достаточно интуитивное, это тот же 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Hub' как например в [MSN Новости](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/news/9c3e8cad-6702-4842-8f61-b8b33cc9caf1), но при использовании 2ух страниц он дает неприглядный результат.